# pull first object from ngrx/store in Angular2

Tags: angular, ngrx

if I have an `ngrx` store that consists of preferences with a sample looking like:

`preferences: [{
    name: 'pref1',
    type: 'boolean',
    value: true
  }, {
    name: 'pref2',
    type: 'boolean',
    value: true
  },
  ...
]`

how would I grab just the first stored preference as an observable chaining off `this._store.select('preferences')`?

I can't find the correct syntax, although I know `rxjs` has a `.first()` method available.  I haven't been able to find a good example of what I'm looking for to make it work.

Comment: The answer will really depend upon what should be emitted from the observable if your array is empty and does not have a first element. It could emit `null` or could chose not to emit anything. However, if the latter is used, the observable would be unable to indicate an array being emptied. You need to include the expected behaviour in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer @Sasxa gave was almost exactly right.  This is the solution I used to get it working:

`this._store.select('preferences')
  .map(preferences => preferences.filter((value, index) => index === 0))`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
this._store.select('preferences')
  .filter((value, index) => index === 0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sasxa, you got me on the right track.  I posted the code I used to get it to work below, but wouldn't have been able to get there without your example.